# Android - New Intent starts particular method

Tags: java, android

I want to start one of my existing activities and force the activity to call a specific method after it starts. Is this possible?

Can I define a method that should be called after creating the activity inside my `Intent`?

For example, something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.app.max.Home.class.myMethod);
```

Comment: more description needed.

Comment: Create an activity, start it with an intent. http://goo.gl/tWsyM

Comment: I have added more info. Maybe I am using the wrong terminology. I am going from one activity to another using intents. Is that correct?

Comment: So when targeting a particular activity can I also specify a method to run?

Comment: I don't think this is a right approach to handle this kind of situation. Why would you want to access the specific method of the activity anyway? The activity has to be initialized first in order to access its methods. Depending on your needs I would suggest you to create a new class with static methods or use approach described by Lukap.

Comment: see my solution

Answer (score 27):

No, I don't think you can have something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.app.max.Home.class.method);
```

but you can do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.app.max.Home.class);
intent.putExtra("methodName","myMethod");
startActivity(intent);
```

and then in the called activity (where you need to start the method), you can take the intent and decide which method to call like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   super.onNewIntent(intent);
   if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("myMethod")){
      mymethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: i tried this, like: 
    ```@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if(intent.getStringExtra("methodName").equals("drawOnJupiter")){
            this.drawView.drawOnJupiter();
        }
        }``` 

with no luck

Comment: It's not calling onNewIntent(). but the activity starts.

Comment: @Imeshke Same issue here, did you find a fix for it?

Comment: this method is only called when your launchMode is set to singleTop or singleTask

Answer (score 6):

Hello You can't call a particular method from intent but alternately you can use a service from intent and your requirement will be done.

> Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

and in MyService.class

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          yourParticularMethod();  //do your task and stop the service when your task is done for battery saving purpose
          context.stopService(new Intent(context, MyService.class)); 

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and register this service in your manifest file like this

```xml
<application>
    <service android:name=".MyService" />
    .
    .
</application>
```

Answer (score 4):

I solve this issue by using `onCreate` instead of `onNewIntent`.

Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.app.max.Home.class);
intent.putExtra("methodName","myMethod");
startActivity(intent);
```

com.app.max.Home Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
    {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null)
        {
            //Extra bundle is null
        }else{
            String method = extras.getString("methodName");

            if (method.equals("myMethod"))
            {
               //Call method here!
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this solution solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You question seems interesting, but there is no way you can do it using `Intent`. You have to understand that when you start an activity, it goes through a life cycle which is : `onCreate()`->`onStart()`-`>OnResume()`. So what you can do is start that method from `onResume()` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myMethod();//start your method from here
}
```

I'm just trying to help,give me some more information about your problem if this approach does not solve your problem.