# how to start a particular function in new activity using intent?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming and finding it difficult to deal with this problem.  Is it possible to call a specific method of another activity using `Intent`?

I tried the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7876643/5229770) post, but since I'm using a database I get the error:

> super.onNewIntent is undefined for sqliteopenhelper.`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To help others to help you, you should post more information. What have you tried? What does not work? What does your code look like currently? For more information on how to write a good post, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Should be fairly straightforward. Define a constant somewhere in your code, either in a `Constants` class or in one of your Activities:

```
public static final String LOAD_METHOD_ID = "load_method_id";
public static final int LOAD_METHOD_CODE = 92840;
```

In `Activity` A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.putIntExtra(LOAD_METHOD_ID, LOAD_METHOD_CODE);
startActivity(i);
```

In `onCreate()` of `Activity` B:

```
int code = getIntent().getIntExtra(LOAD_METHOD_ID, 0);
if (code == LOAD_METHOD_CODE) {
    launchTheMethodHere()
}
```

**Edit:**

Following from your comment, it appears you are trying to access a method inside a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. In this case, you access the methods of that class through creating an instance (typically with a `static getInstance()` method instead of a constructor) of that class, and   call the methods from there. For example [example pulled from [here](http://partisanapps.com/2015/08/really-useful-notes-saving-and-loading-with-a-local-database-i/#creatingthedatabase)]:

```
public MyDbHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//...
private static MyDbHelperClass mInstance = null;

public static synchronized MyDbHelperClass getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MyDbHelperClass(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

And then, inside the class where you want to access a method from, you would use:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity {
//...

MyDbHelperClass db = MyDbHelperClass.getInstance(this);
db.callAMethodFromHelperClass();
```

Comment: It says getIntent method is not defined for sqliteopenhelper class.

Comment: @aditya6348 No, it only applies to classes that extend `Activity`. To access a method inside an `SQLiteOpenHelper` class, you would typically create an instance of that class, and then call the method from there. There is no need to use an `Intent` at all. I'll post an edit in a second to show you what I mean.

Comment: @aditya6348 Ok, take a look at my edit. It should be more relevant to your situation now.